# How to send a URL with php in the background?

Tags: php, url, redirect, process, background

I have a question where I have been struggling with for the past 5 hours. I try to send a url without being redirected to that url. I would like to see it being processed in the background. When I search on google I can only find how to send a url with data. Please someone save me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey Sundar! I tried to do it with curl but it doesn't send the url. This is my code: $runfile="here_is_my_url";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $runfile);
        $content = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        echo $content;

Comment: Can you give more details about your problem? Are you sure is not about using Ajax ?

Comment: did you enable curl module on your server. Please recheck once again. AJAX can be possible if the request will happen on the same domain and the request should happen from the browser. If domain is different then you have to enable the cross origin policy

Comment: Hey Adrian! I have a url that triggers a solr dataimport. If you send that url it starts to grab the changes in the mysql database. So when I update my db objects with a form, I want to send that url as well so it fetches the changes immediately. I work local. Hope this is enough information. If you need more information please tell me!

Comment: Show us your code please: where you're sending your URL **from**, and where you're sending it **to**.